# AngularJS Error: $parse:syntax Syntax Error при загрузки html в ng-init

Tags: php, json, angularjs, model

Имеем textarea:

```
<textarea ng-init="testConditionEdit='<?php echo htmlentities(Tests::getTestCondition($idBlock));?>'" ng-model="testConditionEdit"></textarea>
```

Загружаем с БД некий html блок в модель в директиве `ng-init`, который может иметь разные спецсимволы и т.д. Для преобразования спецсимволов раньше помогала функция `htmlentities`. Но попался блок на который в консоли появляется
[ошибка](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=Pt&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=45&p3=testConditionEdit%3D%27%0A%0A%3Cp)

Вот этот html блок:

```
<p style="font-family:'Pt Sans', Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-style: normal; ">
8. Эксплуатация</p>
```

ругается на `'Pt Sans'`.
Понимаю что правильно подтягивать данные в модель не во вьюхе, а неким ангуляр сервисом в виде jsona. Есть ли способ преобразовывать блок чтобы не было синтаксических в самом html?

Comment: Использовать класс и прикрутить стиль внешним файлом религия не позволяет?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: не в классе дело совсем. `style="font-family:'Pt Sans'` - Это пример контента который подгружается с БД. Контент может быть разным. Кто-то скопировал текст с википедии например. его сохранил в БД вот в таком виде, и его нужно подтянуть в модель

Comment: А если жабаскрипт подсунут который куки ворует, сессии угоняет и прочие пакости делает?

Comment: JS в контенте с БД? это уже второй вопрос) Контент в БД будут наполнять  не все пользователи. как вариант

Comment: Блажен, кто верует. А по теме, чем генерировать через ПХП весь этот салат из `"` и `'`  не проще загружать контент отдельно от презентации?

Comment: ну вот я и думал, контент подгружать в json с сервера и потом уже использовать его в модели

Comment: Сейчас подумал что может прокатить если `'` на `'+'` или `\'` поменять. `echo htmlentities(str_replace("'", "'+'", Tests::getTestCondition($idBlock)))`.

Comment: Помогло `<?php echo htmlentities(addslashes(Tests::getTestCondition($idBlock)));?>`